# How to access value defined application.properties file outside of class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, application.properties

I want to put a value from my application.properties in my @RequestMapping path outside my class.

I know that inside a class you can do something like this:

```
@Value("${property.value}")
private String propertyValue;
```

I need something like this, but cant figure out how to accomplish it:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("{propertyValue}/my/path/")
class MyController(){}
```

Comment: did you try `@RequestMapping("${property.value}/my/path/")`?

Comment: You should normally use `@ConfigurationProperties` instead of `@Value`. In a case like this, have you tried simply including `${property.value}` in your request mapping?

Comment: @Kartik, chrylis. Yea, that solved it. Cant belive I didnt think of that. Thanks!

Comment: well, I had to do it like this: "\${property.value}/my/path/", but that might just be a Kotlin thing